# Как обрабатывать Form.Show()?

Tags: winforms, vb.net

Допустим, есть форма Form1. Периодически в программе она скрывается (Form1.Hide()) и потом снова показывается (From1.Show()). 
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы каждый раз, когда она показывалась, с ней происходили некоторые действия, т.е. я хочу ловить событие From1.Show(). 
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Это обработчик события, хорошо описано в документации Майкрософт.
Приведу код:

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) _ 
     Handles Form1.Shown

   MessageBox.Show("You are in the Form.Shown event.")

End Sub
```

Создать обработчик события можно и более простым способом, чем вручную его объявлять. В окне Properties в Visual Studio нужно выбрать необходимый объект, щелкнуть по значку молнии, и там будут все допустимые события. Щелкаете два раза на имени нужного вам события, обработчик создается, пишете ваш код.

Comment: Shown срабатывает при первом показе формы, разве нет?

Comment: Я нашел другой способ без обработки показа формы. Вопрос закрыт.